# SQL: How to concatenate every group of N rows into a single row

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I have this

```
 ID | Name 
----+-------
 31 | Abby
 24 | Bruce 
 44 | Carl 
 49 | Derek
 55 | Eric
 81 | Fred
```

I want to concatenate groups of N rows into a single row. For N = 3, this would give me this

```
    ID    |    Name 
----------+----------------
 31,24,44 | Abby,Bruce,Carl
 49,55,81 | Derek,Eric,Fred
```

I managed to generate a row to use GROUP BY and CONCAT on, but it only works in mysql...

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT *, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS r1, (@row_number - 1) DIV 3 AS r2 FROM table1

 ID | Name  | r1| r2
----+-------+---+---
 31 | Abby  | 1 | 0
 24 | Bruce | 2 | 0
 44 | Carl  | 3 | 0
 49 | Derek | 4 | 1
 55 | Eric  | 5 | 1
 81 | Fred  | 6 | 1
```

For clarification:

- I want a vanilla-like SQL solution (So it will work in mysql, sybase, oracle and postgres)
- I don't need any order, I just want to reconstitute the original table at some point
- I don't have writing privileges on this base, only reading
- I want to concatenate any columns type (by casting them to a string) and handle NULLs
- It's ok if some groups are not exactly of size N (like the last one)

Answer (score 2):

Amazing script. But I suspect you left out an AS. So I made it like so:

```
select string_agg(t.[id], ',') as ids,
       string_agg(t.[name], ',') as names
from 

(select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from [tablename]
     ) AS t

group by cast( (seqnum - 1) / 3 as int);
```

In my case, it is as such (though I could not get the 'within group (order by id)' to work at any way..... hmmmm)

Here is mine that works well, which is a list of emails to all my students, combined into a row for every 100 rows. The String_Agg limits it to 8000 character, sadly. Anyone knows any alternative to String_Agg for an SQL Server?

```
SELECT 
string_agg(t.[Student Name], ';') as [All Names], 
string_agg(t.[Student Email], ';') as [All Emails]

FROM
(
SELECT [Student Name], [Student Email], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Student Email]) AS RowNo
FROM [Mailing List For Courses] where [Prod Name]='Online Courses'
) AS t
group by cast( (RowNo - 1) / 100 as int);
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Please understand that the answer section is for answers. If you have an answer, then post one answer that includes all of the information, self-contained. **Do not break up your attempted answer across multiple answers**. This is not how Stack Overflow works. Your posts are very confusing since they are broken up, but it **seems more like you have a question**, so please post a **new question**, again self-contained. You can also link to this post if you think it provides context.

Comment: Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL solution looks something like this:

```
select listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids,
       listagg(name, ',') within group (order by id) as names
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by cast( (seqnum - 1) / 3 as int);
```

I think this will work as-is in Oracle.  In MySQL, you need to change `listagg()` to `group_concat()` (and be using MySQL 8+) and in Postgres, you need to change `listagg()` to `string_agg()`.

And, you pretty much can't do this easily in Sybase.

Oh, wait, there is another way:

```
select concat( (case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then concat(id, ';') else '' end),
               (case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then concat(id, ';') else '' end),
               (case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then concat(id, ';') else '' end)
             ) as ids,
       concat( (case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then concat(name, ';') else '' end),
               (case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then concat(name, ';') else '' end),
               (case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then concat(name, ';') else '' end)
             ) as name           
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by cast( (seqnum - 1) / 3 as int);
```

Of course, Sybase doesn't support `concat()`, so you have to use `+`.  And this produces `;` for the separator rather than `,`, but it is pretty close.

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast response. I've read a lot about sybase and from what I understand you need some custom procedures...